# Excel Pulling Origin Info from File Details Section

Tags: vba, excel, scripting

I am writing VBA to pull in the "Last Saved By" user that is identified on under the "Properties" of a file.

I am able to access the "Last Modified Date" & "Last Accessed Date".  But I am completely stumped on getting the "Last Saved By" data.

Please let there be someone out there that knows how to do this!!! :)

[image]

Here is the current code I am using to extract the "Last Modified Date":

```
Function FileLastModifiedDate(strFullFileName As String)
    Dim fs As Object, f As Object, s As String

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(strFullFileName)

    s = UCase(strFullFileName) & vbCrLf
    s = f.datelastmodified
    FileLastModifiedDate = s

    Set fs = Nothing: Set f = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Function` below will work for both ***Excel*** and ***Word*** Files:

```
Function FileLastSavedBy(strFullFileName As String)

Dim fs As Object, f As Object, s As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If UCase(strFullFileName) Like "*XLS*" Then ' <-- check Excel file    
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(strFullFileName)

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)
    FileLastSavedBy = wb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Author")
    wb.Close False
    Set fs = Nothing
    Set f = Nothing

ElseIf UCase(strFullFileName) Like "*DOC*" Then ' <-- check Word file
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(strFullFileName)
    FileLastSavedBy = wordDoc.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Author")

    wordDoc.Close False
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    wordApp.Quit
    Set wordApp = Nothing
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Function
```

***Sub Code*** (to test the Function)

```
Sub testFunc()

Dim a As String
a = FileLastSavedBy("C:\Users\Shai\Desktop\North Carolina.xlsx") '<-- modify this to your file name and path (Excel File)

a = FileLastSavedBy("C:\Users\Shai\Desktop\GanName.Docx") '<-- modify this to your word document name and path (Word document)


MsgBox a

End Sub
```

Comment: @KTate see my code above, let me know if it works as you intended

Comment: thank you for the code.  When I tested it in VBA, I see a reaction from VBA that it is opening the WB but the result was still "#VALUE".

Comment: Strange, it's working for me, how are you using this code ? When you run it in debug mode, what are you getting ?

Comment: excuse my incompetence in advance, but when I attempt to perform this code via the debug mode (F8), I get no feedback from VBA.  What am I missing here to get the result of your provided code?  Thanks!

Comment: @KTate see edited code and added `Sub` to test this function

Comment: when i test the function with a file address, it works up until this line of code:
<code> Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f) <code>

It gives the following error message:
"Run-Time Error '1004': 05.11.2016 - Open Items.docx: file format is not valid"

Comment: @KTate because what you are describing is a **Word** document, not Excel `Workbook` according to your Post

Comment: that is correct.  I am wanting to use an Excel workbook to track the updating/modifying of Word documents within our accounting department.  I have code that does so for the last date saved and last date accessed.  Can this not be done for the last saved authors?

Comment: @KTate try the new updated code I have, it will work for both Excel and Word files

Comment: I received the following error message within VBA: 
"Run-time error '462':
The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable"

Comment: so it works, kinda.  For file addresses on my personal hard drive or personal H:\ drive it seems to work (or at least give the result like it worked).  Where it still gives "#VALUE" at is on items stored on our plants drive.